# PostgreSQL: Pooling LDAP connections

Tags: ldap, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 8.4 configured to authenticate database users by performing a LDAP bind, as described in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-LDAP. It works. However, for each login, it makes a new LDAP connection, sets up SSL, binds, and tears it down immediately afterwards. This is somewhat wasteful.

**Is there any way of pooling these LDAP connections so that each database login only performs a bind, not an entire connection setup and teardown?**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using PAM to authenticate, and configuring PAM to use LDAP?  I think that the PAM LDAP auth module does the connection pooling you're referring to.

Comment: Hmm, maybe, except database users aren't system users.